# how to call python script in kettle

Tags: python, kettle

I have a problem in `kettle` connecting `python`. In `kettle`, I only find the `js` script module.

Does kettle support python directly? I mean, can I call a python script in `kettle` without using `js` or others?

By the way, I want to move data from `Oracle` to `Mongo` regularly. I choose to use `python` to implement the transformation. So without external files, does it have some easy methods to keep the synchronization between a relational db and a no-rdb?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt support it directly from what I've seen.

However there is a mongodb input step. And a lot of work has been done on it recently ( and still ongoing.

So given there is a mongodb input step, if you're using an ETL tool already then why would you want to make it execute a python script to do the job??

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I have called the python script with shell in kettle. I didn't use the mongodb input step,because I found that I must 'get fields' when I use this mongooutput component.So here I have many target collections,and I can't solve the problem yet that the collection name is a variable... Do you have any idea?

Comment: ah ok interesting.  I vaguely recall a question along these lines in the Jira - I'd check there ( jira.pentaho.com ) and if not then ask on the IRC channel ##pentaho on Freenode.  Also they do Kettle office hours once a week in IRC so you can actually talk to a Kettle developer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll have a try and if you come up with some ideas,please tell me :)

Comment: @Gentlezerg: Have you been able to call the Python script from Kettle?